# spring boot application load balanced with apache

Tags: apache, spring-boot, load-balancing

I have an application with multiple modules

- Two spring boot backends, that exports json services to frontend
- A frontend node.js application
- Several php pages served from an apache server

Web browsers comunicates only with apache server, who routes requests to these applications (using virutal hosts and redirects).

- admin.myapp.com (php and node.js frontends)
- api.myapp.com (services backend)
- scheduler.myapp.com (scheduler backend)

[For more clarity, here's a graphic explanation of this distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bc9p1.png)

Here's virtual host configuration for backend

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ServerName api.myapp.com
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

I need to implement HA **only** for backend application **keeping** the software instances (ie. I cant add a new apache dedicated instance for balancing).

I cant figure out how to do this, tutorials i've readed explain how to transform an entire apache instance into a load balancer, but I only need to bring HA to one virtual host (backend services) keeping software instances as they are now.

I'll appreciate any help.

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Httpd documentation is pretty confusing at first sight, it does not merge concepts,e.g, Virtual hosts with Balancers. But I still extracting much info from their [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html).

A basic approach is to set a balancer and its members, then proxy everything to it.

To accomplish that we will need a few modules installed: `sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_http proxy_balancer lbmethod_byrequests` must be enough, otherwise, check the logs for missing modules or recommendations.

Then, fill the gaps within your virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName api.myapp.com
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off
        #Your balanced backends
        <Proxy balancer://backend-cluster>
                BalancerMember http://localhost:3000
                BalancerMember http://localhost:9000
                ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
        </Proxy>
        #Balancer admin interface for localhost access
        <Location /balancer-manager>
                SetHandler balancer-manager
                Order allow,deny
                allow from localhost 
        </Location>

        ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
        #Proxying everything to your backends
        ProxyPass / balancer://backend-cluster/

</VirtualHost>
```

Httpd also provides few other algorithms for balancing your requests. As you can see, the provided example balances with *byrequest*(in a nutshell, shares requests between members). The remaining ones are(I encourage you to read the docs):

- **bytraffic** - Share load by the amount of traffic per member
- **bybusyness** - Members with a lower number of jobs are selected
- **heartbeat** -  Uses mod_heartbeat to balance the work

This minimal configuration must be enough to achieve a minimal HA backend services.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This is exactly what I need ... I'll follow this aproach making focus on those modules.